# Is it possible to attach an unversioned file to a pull request?

Tags: tfs

In TFS, is it possible to attach a non-versioned file to a pull request? We use pull requests as documentation of code review and would like to attach proof of testing to pull requests so the evidence is all in the same place.

Our proof of integration testing is usually as a PDF with attached screenshots, hence the question.

We are using TFS Version 16.122.27102.1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you mean attach the non-source controlled files in pull request comments, it's Markdown supported.

> **[Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=vsts#attachments)**
>
> In pull request comments and wiki pages, you can attach files to
>   illustrate your point or to give more detailed reasoning behind your
>   suggestions. To attach a file, drag and drop it into the comment field
>   or wiki page edit experience. You can also select the paper-clip icon
>   in the upper-right of the comment box or the format pane in wiki page.

[image]